# Is it possible to restrict to multiple roles in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

currently i am restricting to admin and user, but it seems i have to introduce more roles as well.

the current code I have is:

```
<WithPermissions render={({ permissions }) => (
  permissions === 'admin' ?
    <MenuItemLink
        to={`/ads-featured`}
        primaryText="Promóciók"
        leftIcon={<promo.icon />}
        onClick={onMenuClick}
    /> : null
  )}
/>
```

But i need something like:

```
permissions === 'admin' or permissions === 'hirdeto'
```

is it possible? if yes what's the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<WithPermissions render={({ permissions }) => (
    permissions === 'admin' || permissions === 'hirdeto' ?
      <MenuItemLink
          to={`/ads-featured`}
          primaryText="Promóciók"
          leftIcon={<promo.icon />}
          onClick={onMenuClick}
      /> : null
  )}
/>
```